# OpenStreamForWriteAsync leaves extra bytes

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a situation where my file changes sizes (things added and deleted frequently). The user has the option to save their file. However, if they save their file OVER an existing file that is larger (which they are allowed to do), then it scrambles the file by leaving extra crud at the end from the file that was larger.

For example, I have the following code:

```
        // The user saves their data to disk. No problem.
        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";

        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    sw.Write("ABCDEFGH");
                }
            }
        }

        // The user saves their data to disk again, overwriting their first file.
        FileSavePicker savePicker2 = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker2.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        savePicker2.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
        savePicker2.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";

        StorageFile file2 = await savePicker2.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file2 != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await file2.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    sw.Write("1234");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When this code is finished, my resulting file is 1234EFGH, not 1234, as I had expected.

What am I doing wrong? I can't just delete the file between the two calls or the StorageFile will crash on `OpenStreamAForWriteAsync(...)`

Comment: `stream.SetLength(stream.Position)`?

Comment: That was the answer. You should post it as the answer so that I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut tail of the stream if you overwriting the existing file adjust length of the stream to match last position (make sure to flush stream/writer before updating length):

```
     stream.SetLength(stream.Position);
```